# getBroadcast and getService of PendingIntent

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-pendingintent

Can request codes of requestCode the same for getBroadcast and getService?
For instance,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(INTENT_FILTER);
PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctx, requestCode, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
am.cancel(sender);
sender.cancel();

Intent intentS = new Intent(ctx, MyService.class);
PendingIntent senderS = PendingIntent.getService(ctx, requestCode, intentS, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

am.cancel(senderS);
senderS.cancel();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Because there are other factors that can be used to differentiate the `PendingIntent`s. In your case `sender` has an ACTION, whereas `senderS` has no ACTION, but has a component (package and class).